# Python: Running Flask with gunicorn produces error "Failed to find application object"

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

I have a pretty big Flask project I'm trying to run with gunicorn, supervisor and nginx. I am using lots of Blueprints and have one file called `run.py` that starts the whole application. It looks like this:

```
from webapp import app, socketio
if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

`webapp` ist the main module that contains all the views, models and template files.

When I try to bind gunicorn `gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 run &` it produces the following error:
`Failed to find application object 'application' in 'run'`. I have no idea how to fix this problem.

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/deploy-flask-app-with-nginx-using-gunicorn-and-supervisor-d7a93aa07c18).

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial mentioned gunicorn is started by

```
gunicorn app:app -b localhost:8000
```

i.e. there is that `:app` part that is not in

```
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 run
```

which should probably be

```
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 run:app
```

Comment: This doesn't work. That's why I changed it to `run` only.